# jquery / noscript to fade a page in

Tags: jquery, animation, accessibility, opacity, fadein

How's this for accessibility? I'm looking for a (reasonably) bulletproof solution that doesn't show a flash of the content before hiding it. I tried the accepted solution on this post ( [How to fade in an entire web page -- accessibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042670/how-to-fade-in-an-entire-web-page-accessibly) ) and it seems to work well - anything I'm missing? Aside from doctype and charset, etc.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.hidden').fadeTo(2000, 1);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .hidden { opacity:0; }  
        body > div { background:#ccc; position:absolute; top:20%; right:20%; bottom:20%; left:20%; padding:20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>$("body").addClass("hidden");</script>
    <div>hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That solution was from 2011, this day and age you can probably handle the fade transition with CSS3. https://jsfiddle.net/px9gjdc4/

**CSS**

```
body {
  opacity: 0; /* start hidden, no flash of content */
  transition: opacity 2s; /* transition the opacity property */
}

body.reveal {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $(window).load(function(){
        // add this class once page content has loaded
        $('body').addClass('reveal');
      });
    });
  </script>
  ... 
</body>
```

**EDIT:** If you're concerned about JS being disabled, you can go the *pure* CSS3 approach using animations. https://jsfiddle.net/px9gjdc4/2/

**CSS**

```
body {
  opacity: 0; /* start hidden, no flash of content */
  animation-name: reveal;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>...</body>
```

The only drawback is that the page is not guaranteed to have fully loaded by the time you're fading in. Might be worth adding an `animation-delay` property to your CSS to mitigate that risk.

Comment: My concern is all the "what ifs" - what if they've got javascript disabled, so reveal is never added as a class, so they never see anything? that's why i added the class of hidden in a script at the top of <body>